# C# - How to create constructor for inherited class where parent class only has static constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, static

For example, say I wanted to create a class that inherits System.Diagnostics.StopWatch, and for this example pretend that System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew() is the only public constructor for that class (I know its not, but I'm trying to inherit a different class where that is the case) :

```
public class Example : System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
{
    public Example()
    {
        // ... return System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }
}
```

I know there are obvious workarounds, but just wondering if this is possible in C#

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: `StartNew()` isnt a constructor

Comment: The best you can do is `public static new Example StartNew()
    {
        var e = new Example();
        e.Start();
        return e;
    }`

Comment: Often classes are designed this way for the specific purpose of preventing inheritance. If there are no accessible constructors then you can't inherit from the class.

Comment: Please show your real case so we can really help you.

Comment: All classes except static classes have a constructor.  You can derive from a class unless (a) it is sealed, or (b) no constructors are publicly visible (either private or internal).

Comment: @joe you can derive from a class with only a private or internal constructor just fine. It only needs to be accesible and that depends on *where* the derived types is being implemented.

Comment: @InBetween Other then using a nested class, how would you derive from a class that only has a private constructor?

Comment: @ZoharPeled There is no other option, but thats not relevant. The point is that saying *you can derive from a class unless (a) it is sealed, or (b) no constructors are publicly visible (either private or internal* is false. `internal` is obvious, but maybe the `private` one isn't. Nested classes deriving form the enclosing class is acutally a really useful and nifty pattern.

Comment: @InBetween, though strictly speaking your counterexamples are correct (you can derive an internal class from an internal class in the same assembly, and a nested class can derive from its enclosing class), I don't think either of them is relevant to the OP's question.  The OP's example suggests they are trying to derive a public class from a class in a different assembly.

Answer (score 4):

There are basically three scenarios where you can't inherit from a class:

1. The intended parent class is declared as sealed, which prohibits inheriting from it.
2. The intended parent class doesn't have an accessible constructor.
3. The intended parent class is a static class.

If you are in one of these 3 scenarios, you will not be able to inherit from that class, plain and simple, don't look for a usable workaround because there isn't.

Comment: Case 2 is not technically correct. In C# 5 you can declare class like this: `class B { private B() } class D: B { D(): this(1) { } D(int i): this() { } }` which does not reference base class constructor, thus its accessibility does not matter.

Comment: @PetSerAl If that compiles in c#5 (can’t test it now) then it’s a compiler bug, not a language feature. It sure doesn’t compile in the current version, if it did you’d get a StackOverflowException when run.